# Azure VM Migrate Classic to RM

Tags: azure, azure-networking

i want to move my VMs from classic model to RM model.

i dont want to use migaz or platform supported because all resource will be name "RG-Migrated" thats why i i think better to create new VM from VHD.

But how to keep same internet IP on that case ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a reserved IP attached to a deployment, the only possible path is to migrate the deployment entirely. In classic, you don't have an IP as a resource that you can manipulate, it works more like a feature than a separated object.

That said, only the resource group will have the suffix "-Migrated" post-migration if you use PowerShell (the recommneded approach). You can then move the resources to any other resource group that you want.

[Migrate IaaS resources from classic to Azure Resource Manager by using Azure PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)